# Why does this C code segfault when I use | instead of ||?

Tags: c

The following code segfaults whenever I use short-circuit-or (`|`), and compiles flawlessly when not short-circuited (`||`)?

Compiled using `gcc -Wall ../IsNull/IsNull.c ../IsEmpty/IsEmpty.c *.c -o IsNullOrEmpty`:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "../IsNull/IsNull.h"
#include "../IsEmpty/IsEmpty.h"

#include "IsNullOrEmpty.h"

_Bool isNullOrEmpty (char *str);

_Bool isNullOrEmpty (char *str) {
    return (isNull (str) | isEmpty (str));     
} /* end of isNullOrEmpty() */
```

Comment: What is the definition of `isNULL`?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't crashing when you *don't* short-circuit? That makes more sense.

Comment: `str` might also not be null when passed in, but refers to data your program no longer has access to. Have you loaded the program in a debugger to see the value of `str`?

Comment: @oldrinb: i just edited the snippet above, it crashes when I use "|".

Comment: @DavidBrown: here, _Bool isNull (char *str);

Comment: Please can we have the full picture?

Comment: Note that the whole point of `<stdbool.h>` is to let you write `bool` rather than `_Bool`. If you're not going to use `bool`, you don't need to include `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: @EdHeal: I have 3 folders namely IsNull, IsEmpty, and IsNullOrEmpty. Each folder contains 3 files - <IsNull/IsEmpty/IsNullOrEmpty>.c, <IsNull/IsEmpty/IsNullOrEmpty>.h, and <IsNullTest/IsEmptyTest/IsNullOrEmptyTest>.c. IsNullOrEmpty.c contains the above snippet, IsNull just contains return str == NULL; and IsEmpty just contains return (strlen (str) == 0); that's it.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman: I'm using _Bool.

Comment: @chrismsawi Yes, I noticed, hence my remark.

Comment: Requests for definitions of isNull, or the full picture, or suggestions that `str` might be inaccessible, miss the rather obvious point that if `str` is NULL, `isEmpty(NULL)` will be called regardless of what isNull returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using `||` (*logical* or operator) instead of `|` (*bitwise* or operator). The former short-circuits whilst the latter does **not**, hence the segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks! problem became more clarified to me.

Answer (score 2):

The bitwise Or ( `|` ) can't be short-circuted, because is not part of a boolean expression. It is just an operation ( like a sum ) and so each side  *must* be executed in order to produce the result that actually is the bit per bit `or` of the two values returned by your functions.